# Please merge tags [pendingintent], [android-pendingintent] and [pending-intent]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

Since this is android-specific, it would probably be best if the "master" tag was [android-pendingintent](/questions/tagged/android-pendingintent) and the others become synonyms. I would suggest it myself, but my tag-specific reputation is spread across all 3 tags.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for that, but you've created a tag **androind-pendingintent** that is spelled incorrectly. Please fix.